# nginx and thin : how to know that request is handle by nginx and not thin server?

Tags: nginx, thin

I have installed nginx as a web server and thin as a application server.i am runing three instances of thin server on port 3000,3001 and 3002 respectively.i am running nginx on port 8080.

when i send http requst to my mascine everything works fine.but when I stop my nginx server(thin server is still running) and send HTTP request to my maschine it still works.my question is why the HTTP requst is working when I have stoped my Nginx server???

also if both nginx and thin servers are running then how we will come to know that request is handle by nginx and not thin server??

thanks

Comment: after turning nginx off, run `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 80`, what output do you get

Comment: Do you see all request going to one server when you stop nginx if not then it obvious that thin would be doing the load balancing which was done by nginx earlier